# pyspark.pandas: Converting float64 column to TimedeltaIndex

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I want to convert a numeric column which is resembling a timedelta in seconds to a `ps.TimedeltaIndex` (for the purpose of later resampling the dataset)

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps

df = ps.DataFrame({"time": [2.0, 3.0, 4.0], "x": [4.5, 4.0, 3.5]})
df.set_index(ps.to_timedelta(df.time, "s").to_numpy())

KeyError: '2000000000 nanoseconds'
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @koedlt brought me on the right track, but is still missing the conversion to `TimedeltaIndex`

```
df = ps.DataFrame({"time": [2.0, 3.0, 4.0], "x": [4.5, 4.0, 3.5]})
df["time"] = ps.to_timedelta(df.time, unit="s")
df.set_index("time", inplace=True)
```

However I also realised that [`resample`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) I mentioned requires actually a `DatetimeIndex`, so I should have asked for that. We'd need to use [`ps.to_datetime`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.to_datetime.html)`(df.time, unit="s")` instead of `ps.to_timedelta` in this case

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because [`set_index`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/python/pyspark/pandas/frame.py#L4050-L4118) requires column names for its `keys` argument, not the data of the columns.

So you could create a column, and then set it as index:

```py
import pyspark.pandas as ps
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = ps.DataFrame({"time": [2, 3, 4], "x": [4.5, 3, 3.5]})

df["time_nanoseconds"] = F.col("time") * 1e9
df.set_index("time_nanoseconds")

                  time    x                                                     
time_nanoseconds           
2.000000e+09         2  4.5
3.000000e+09         3  3.0
4.000000e+09         4  3.5
```